# Why can't we access global non-static variable from within a class?

Tags: c++

I defined the following structure to be used across the application by several classes.

*ZHTypes.h*

```
#ifndef ZHTypes_h
#define ZHTypes_h

struct BeingHitParams
{
    bool isApplyKnockBack=true;
};
BeingHitParams *default_BeingHitParams_ptr = new BeingHitParams();

#endif
```

I defined a following variable

```
default_BeingHitParams_ptr
```

for the case the I will use it in several places for default parameters of function as I don't need to create a new structure all the time.

Anyway, the above defined variable produces linking error whenever I refer to it in the code inside a class. But if I add **static** in front then it works fine.

```
static BeingHitParams *default_BeingHitParams_ptr = new BeingHitParams();
```

So my question is why can't we access global but non-static variable from within a class?
I also want to know additional explanation of why C++ is restricted in accessing variable like in the situation above.

Comment: The `BeingHitParams *default_BeingHitParams_ptr = new BeingHitParams();` part belongs into a cpp file, not a header.

Comment: Don't define globals in header files.

Comment: or yet even better: avoid using globals completely if possible.

Comment: Some thoughts about global in c++.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544462/global-variables-and-scope-c

Comment: @RobertP. I'm not sure I'd say the top answer there gave a *better* solution. It still has all the problems of global state.

Comment: @sftrabbit - only some thoughts - no rating ;-)

Comment: Why use globals? Why put them in a struct? Why use a pointer? Why the dynamic allocation? Did you use to write a lot of Java?  :-)

Comment: @Liho Any difference if we define it via #define (in general case) ?

Comment: @haxpor: `#define` is directive for preprocessor.. it's just a textual replacement within your code before it is compiled. `#define` is even worse than `const` global, because you lose information about the type of your constant. `BeingHitParams* default_BeingHitParams_ptr` doesn't seem to be a constant though.

Comment: I use it to access global settings like attack points, distance knock-off, sfx path, etc I think pack it up in one single file would give flexibility. Can you suggest the better way?

Comment: @Bopersson I use struct pointer with a thought that I don't need to do any shallow or deep copy every time I pass through functions. Thanks for mentioning about dynamic allocation, I guess it's not necessary.

Comment: I have defined configurations and settings via #define a lot packing in a single header file and it's accessed by other game object classes. Is that a bad design? Is there a better way to do it?
(I just feel this comment question is still relating to the main question. It's my last question in comment section here.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you put `static` in front of it then you are giving it internal linkage and each translation unit that includes that header has their own copy of `default_BeingHitParams_ptr`. What you actually want to do is declare it `extern` in the header file (which not only makes it have external linkage but also makes it a declaration rather than a definition) and then define it in a single translation unit:

```
// ZHTypes.h
// Now this is just a declaration:
extern BeingHitParams *default_BeingHitParams_ptr;

// ZHTypes.cpp
// Defined in a single translation unit:
BeingHitParams* default_BeingHitParams_ptr = new BeingHitParams();
```

However, introducing global state is [usually a bad thing](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

Comment: @sftrabbit Can't #ifndef prevent the multiple translation unit (as per your explanation)?

Comment: @haxpor `#ifndef` inclusion guards only prevent a header from being included multiple times in a *single* translation unit. You almost certainly *want* a header to be included across multiple translation units.