# threading from a static member in dll

Tags: multithreading, dll, static

I have a problem lunching a thread within a class A for example where the class A is a static member of class B with in a dll. I am using Visual Studio 9 and boost 1.40. Please consider the following code:

mylib.h:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <windows.h>

#ifdef FOO_STATIC
    #define FOO_API
#else
    #ifdef FOO_EXPORT
    #define FOO_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
    #define FOO_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#endif


class FOO_API foo{
    boost::thread* thrd;
    public:
    foo();
    ~foo();
    void do_work();
};

class FOO_API bar{
    static foo f;
public:
    static foo& instance();
};
```

mylib.cpp:

```
#include "mylib.h"

foo::foo() 
{
    thrd = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&foo::do_work,this));
}

foo::~foo(){
    thrd->join();
    delete thrd;
}

void foo::do_work(){
    printf("doing some works\n");
}

foo& bar::instance(){return f;}

foo bar::f;
```

in the executable application, I have:

main.cpp:

```
#include "mylib.h"
void main(){
    bar::instance();
}
```

If I link mylib statically to the executable app, It prints out "doing some works", while if I link it dynamically (dll), it does nothing.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Use a debugger.  Compile with /MD.

Answer (score 0):

Your program could be exiting before the thread completes. You might try waiting after the `bar::instance()` call, or joining the thread in `main`. Something else to try would be to flush stdout after the `printf` call.

Comment: You are right. I have to either wait after <code>bar::instance()</code> or join the thread in <code>main</code>.

Comment: So my question is if there is an static object who creates a thread or more internally through shared_ptr for example, what would be the proper way to exit the application since I have no means to join the thread or wait for them to get completed inside the main app.

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> If your DLL is linked with the C
>   run-time library (CRT), the entry
>   point provided by the CRT calls the
>   constructors and destructors for
>   global and static C++ objects.
>   Therefore, these restrictions **(*)** for
>   DllMain also apply to constructors and
>   destructors and any code that is
>   called from them.

**(*)** The restrictions include communicating with threads.

It's best to make the global variable a pointer, and construct and release the object in dedicated callback routines.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75701/what-happens-to-global-variables-declared-in-a-dll/78235#78235) helpful SO answer.