# Linking mingw64 C application to WebAssembly Binaryen C API

Tags: webassembly, mingw-w64

I'm on Windows/mingw64 and trying to generate webassembly with the [Binaryen C API](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen/wiki/Compiling-to-WebAssembly-with-Binaryen#c-api) from a C application. I compiled the binaryen shared library `libbinaryen.dll` without problems, and tried to reproduce the [hello world example](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen/blob/main/test/example/c-api-hello-world.c). It compiles and executes as expected, but it hangs on exit from `main()`, both with a `return` and with `exit()`.

I thought there might be something wrong with exception handling since the Binaryen DLL is C++, but I see the same hang on `main()` exit whether I compile and link with `gcc` or `g++`. Interestingly, if I compile the Binaryen as a static link library (`libbinaryen.a`) and link that to my executable, the problem goes away, but this requires compiling with `g++`. And it generates a 16Mb executable, so I'd rather not do that.

I'm using Mingw version x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, gcc 8.1.0, and linking with `-lmingw32 -lbinaryen`. I have tried linking either directly to the DLL and to the link library, same result.

I'm guessing there is some problem with C/C++ interoperability here, but can't figure out what. The problem also causes `gdb` to hang upon `main()` exit, so I haven't been able to pinpoint exactly what happens.

Anyone seen this kind of behavior when calling C++ DLLs from C on mingw?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the cause now, posting it here for reference. It looks like the Binaryen library [contains a static object](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen/blob/main/src/support/threads.cpp) `ThreadPool` for keeping track of threads, and since it's a DLL this object's [destructors are not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500229/c-static-objects-in-dlls-not-having-destructors-called) when closing down, which leads to a threading deadlock when exiting `main()`. Limiting Binaryen to a single thread by defining `BINARYEN_CORES = 1` prevents instantiating the `ThreadPool` object and eliminates the problem.

It looks like this is [an open issue](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/7096) with mingw/msys, hopefully it will be resolved in the near future.