# What are the semantics of non-POD objects declared globally in shared libraries?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

If a C++ class with nontrivial constructors and destructors is instantiated globally in a shared library, is its constructor called when the library is loaded, and similarly, is its destructor called when the library is unloaded?  Is this a guarantee, or does it just usually happen?  Can it ever not happen?

Comment: I believe shared library behaviour is platform specific and depends on the ABI used. For ELF defines ctor and dtor list, and the system should respect them.

Comment: Related explanations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373061/what-happens-to-global-and-static-variables-in-a-shared-library-when-it-is-dynam and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75701/what-happens-to-global-variables-declared-in-a-dll

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the constructors and destructors will always be called when the library is loaded or unloaded.

Comment: Can you cite a source for this?  I don't even remember why I was asking this, it was almost a year ago. But I'd still like to know.